# What can I do when an external client try to run a PHP script on my server?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-security

I have a LAMP configured server and multiple times from the Apache error log file I can see warning messages like this one:

```
[Thu Jul 02 08:54:04.263981 2015] [:error] [pid 12059] [client 5.45.79.44:49144] script '/var/www/html/wp-update.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://example.org/wp-update.php
```

Currently I have `mod_security` and inside Wordpress Wordfence enabled.

What should be done in such cases to protect and prevent from these attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warning messages can be ignored, since they are generated when Apache can't find the requested file (404) or permission to the requested file is denied (403).

I see tons of such messages daily in my server logs and the reason they appear is, that some automated scripts try to check your server for vulnerable/insecure scripts, that the admin may have forgotten. Lately I even noticed, that those kind of mass-requests even target SSH keys (GET /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa - just in case the server admin really misconfigured the server).

Running `mod_security` on your server with a tight ruleset (e.g. [OWASP CRS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project)) gives you a good basic **protection** against various kind of known/unknown attacks.